# How to identify added layers with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm using the `layeradd` event:

```
map.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // do something related to the layer that was added
})
```

but I'm not able to determine which layer was actually added.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8prgx/6/).  View the fiddle with your dev tools open and explore the output in the console when you activate one of the two overlays.

When I look at the output in the console, I can see that the "Catskill Creek" feature, for example, was turned on, but I see nothing identifying which overlay this feature belongs to.  (I can't tell which overlay triggered the layeradd event.)

Surely it must be there somewhere...?

Comment: I believe ```e.layer``` is the layer object literal. So you can do an object comparison between ```e.layer``` (which is the layer in the event) and the layer object itself that you added to the map.

Comment: `e.layer` turns out to be a feature of the layer (leaflet just calls them layers)